# Akka persistence deserialization issues for scala List during migration to Scala 2.13 from Scala 2.11

Tags: java, scala, akka-persistence

I am working on a akka/scala application and migrating from scala 2.11 to 2.13. There are some persisted objects (persisted using Scala 2.11) that have scala.collection.immutable.List type (defined as target: List[]).
After migration to Scala 2.13, at the time of replaying the states and during deserialization its failing with below error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy

Could you please help?

Comment: Scala 2.11 and 2.13 aren't serialization-compatible. The collections implementations are very different.

Comment: Did you use java serialization? If yes, there is nothing you can do but read our old data with scala 2.11, convert it into "common" format (proto, json, ...), migrate to 2.13 and read the new format of your data. Also, java serialization must not be used. It has security problems, not performant as well as these incompatibility issues

Comment: Thank you both SethTisue Ivan Stanislavciuc. Ivan, I am using Akka serialization and deserialization, using akka.serialization.SerializationExtension. Seems like SerializationExtension picks the serializer that have been defined for Custom objects and the custom objects use JavaSerializer. Can say its using Java Serialization

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Could you please suggest the best way to convert the existing 2.11 persisted data into common format i.e. json and migrate to 2.13?Would be a great help

Comment: This is basically a migration - pick 2.11 app, use its code to fetch data in deserialized form, serialize it using a new format (that you have to implement because you apparently didn't have before) and store it somewhere - send it to a new implementation via gRPC, store in DB, post on Kafka or whatever. No shortcuts here. I spend several weeks doing migration between services (writing protobufs, setting up infra, validating results, etc), so sorry but no magic snippet to do this for you.

Comment: totally agree with @MateuszKubuszok. Vinny, also please note that json might be having similiar issues in the future when there are breaking changes introduced into json format. You should consider using format that supports schema evolution, like protocol buffers or avro